# How to track or dump all process memory throughtout process's lifetime?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, process

There are several tools that exist for dumping process memory. I like to use `procdump` for simplicity.

**Problem**

The issue I am currently facing with all of these tools is that they will dump process memory "snapshot" for an instant in time. So the process memory will be dumped for the instant I initiate `procdump`. All process memory before and after the dump was initiated is lost.

**What I have done**

I implemented a `powershell` script that dumps memory every 5 seconds. [This commercial forensics tool](https://www.magnetforensics.com/blog/magnet-process-capture/) also seems to provide a way to do the same.

**Question**

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way I can track all process memory throughout its lifetime such that no information is lost? Basically, I am looking for a method/tool/script that is able to capture everything in the process's memory space throughout its lifetime (let's say, the process lifetime is 2 minutes). How to *record* process memory space over time?

Comment: Want do you plan to do with the data?  Are you troubleshooting an issue?

Comment: Doesn't exist. Better come up with another idea for debugging, or run the process inside a debugger.

Comment: If a process takes up only 100 kB memory, and updates itself at only 1,000 Hz, you'd have to record 100 MB/sec. Of course, I picked arbitrarily low numbers. Better to find a way to **step** through execution, e.g. in VM.